# Understanding the usage of \b in regex that matches multiple strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I just found the below regex online while browsing:

```
(?:^|\b)(bitcoin atm|new text|bitcoin|test a|test)(?!\w)
```

I was just curious to know what is the advantage of using `(?:^|\b)` here ?

I understand that basically (?:) means it a non capturing group but I am a bit stumped by `^|\b` in this particular parenthesis, here I understand that `^` basically means asset start of string.

The examples of `\b` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) gave me a fair understanding of what `\b` does, but I am still not able to put things into context based on the example I have provided.

Answer (score 2):

The `(?:^|\b)` is a non-capturing group that contains 2 alternatives both of which are *zero-width assertions*. That means, they just match locations in a string, and thus do not affect the *text* you get in the match.

Besides, as the next subpattern matches `b`, `n` or `t` as the first char (a *word* char) the `\b` (a word boundary) in the first non-capturing group will also match them in the beginning of a string, making `^` (start of string anchor) alternative branch *redundant* here.

Thus, you may safely use

```
\b(bitcoin atm|new text|bitcoin|test a|test)(?!\w)
```

and even

```
\b(bitcoin atm|new text|bitcoin|test a|test)\b
```

since the alternatives end with a word char here.

If the alternatives in the `(bitcoin atm|new text|bitcoin|test a|test)` group are user-defined, dynamic, and can start or end with a non-word char, then the `(?:^|\b)` and `(?!\w)` regex patterns makes sense, but it would not be prcise then, as `(?:^|\b)\.txt(?!\w)` will not match `.txt` as a whole word, it should be preceded with a word char then. I would use `(?:^|\W)` rather than `(?:^|\b)`.

Comment: In the non-capture group `(?:^|\b)` what exactly is `|` for ?

Comment: Same as in the capturing group: `|` is an [alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). Either start of a string or a word boundary.